# Read An array from a file into a perl array

Tags: arrays, json, perl, file

i have a file shown like below:

```
{
"status": "success",
"msg": {
    "status": "success",
    "inscount": 2,
    "critical": 0,
    "result": [
        {
            "Insulin": "Insuman Rapid",
            "morning change": 0,
            "noon change": 1,
            "evening change": 0,
            "action": 3,
            "change morning from": "22",
            "change noon from": "9",
            "change evening from": "20",
            "change morning to": "22",
            "change noon to": "12",
            "change evening to": "20",
            "change type": "1"
        },
        {
            "Insulin": "Insuman basal",
            "morning change": 0,
            "noon change": 0,
            "evening change": 0,
            "action": null,
            "change morning from": "7",
            "change noon from": "6",
            "change evening from": "8",
            "change morning to": "7",
            "change noon to": "6",
            "change evening to": "8",
            "change type": “1”
        }
    ],
    "balance": "9974"
}
```

}

this is a JSON response from a web service and i am saving it into a temp. file.
i want to extract the result array into a perl array of object.

it was generated with the following service call

```
system("curl -X POST -H '$CONTENT_TYPE'  -d '$ARGS'  -o  $TEMP_FILE  $SERVICE_URL 2>/dev/null");
```

I am using this code to extract the status, critical and inscount

```
    if (open(OUTFILE,"<$TEMP_FILE")) {
    while(<OUTFILE>) {
        chomp;
        if (/status\"?\:\s*\"success\"/) {
            $SUCCESS=1;
            print"Success File open********* Febin :) \n";
        }

        if (/critical\"?\:\s*\"1\"/) {
            $CRITICAL=1;
        }

        if (/change type\"?\:\s*\"(\d+)\"/) {
            $CHANGE_TYPE=$1;
        }

        if (/balance\"?\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/) {
            $BALANCE=$1;
        }

        foreach $key (keys %TIME_VALUES) {
            if(/$key\schange\"?\:\s*\"1\"/) {
                $TIME_VALUES{$key}[0] = 1;
            }

            if(/change $key from\"?\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/) {
                $TIME_VALUES{$key}[1] = $1;
            }

            if(/change $key to\"?\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/) {
                $TIME_VALUES{$key}[2] = $1;
            }
        }
    }
    close(OUTFILE);
```

is there any way to do this please help

> ***i am new to perl scripting***

Comment: Also, why the need to save to a temp file when you can use LWP + a JSON parsing module from CPAN?

Comment: @john jensen. because i am editing an existing asterisk IVR code it has been done before by someone else. With a Change in service the Json response will send result as an array before this it was not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe don't understand fully the question, but IMHO the following can work:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use JSON::XS;
use Encode;
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = "./data.json";
my $data = decode_json Encode::encode 'utf8', read_file $file, { binmode => ':utf8' } ;

my $res;
$res->{$_} = $data->{msg}->{$_} for( qw(status critical inscount));

say Dumper $res;
```

for the your input file produces:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'critical' => 0,
          'inscount' => 2,
          'status' => 'success'
        };
```

You should to use JSON::XS for parsing JSON to internal perl structure, and can omit the `encode/utf` parts if your data is only ascii...

EDIT - for increased readability - commented:

```
use Modern::Perl;  #use some modern perl features, like: say and strict and warnings

                   #"load" some modules:
use JSON::XS;      #for the JSON parsing
use Encode;        #module for encoding from/to different encodings
use File::Slurp;   #module for reading files into a variable
use Data::Dumper;  #module for dumping data structures

my $file = "./data.json";  #the filename, where your "JSON" data is

#read the file content into the variable (read_file - provided by the File::SLurp)
my $json_from_file = read_file $file, { binmode => ':utf8' };

#encode
my $encoded_json = Encode::encode 'utf8', $json_from_file;

#convert JSON to internal perl-data structure
my $perl_data = decode_json $encoded_json;

say "=== the data structure ===";
say Dumper $perl_data;

# copy the needed data
my $status   = $perl_data->{msg}->{status};
my $critical = $perl_data->{msg}->{critical};
my $inscount = $perl_data->{msg}->{inscount};
#this is useless, because you can use the $perl_data->{msg}->{status} directly
```

Comment: but i want to read this from the file

Comment: That's exactly what he's doing

Comment: @FebinFathah added explanation

Comment: this code is working for me